# Github actions codecov v2 config reference unknown

Tags: github, github-actions, codecov

I'm using the [Codecovv2 GitHub action](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action) in my project but am struggling with getting any of the configuration to work with my workflow file.

I have a `codecov.yml` file inside of my `workflows` folder that runs *(I'll attach this)* but cannot seem to configure the action through my workflow using any of the config from [here](https://docs.codecov.com/docs/common-recipe-list)

What am I missing?

I'm trying to [ease my coverage](https://docs.codecov.com/docs/common-recipe-list#ease-target-coverage) tests:

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Codecov report

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on pull request events but only for the main branch
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Set up Node js
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      # install npm dependencies
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      # Run unit tests
      - name: Run unit tests
        run: npm run test:unit

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
        with:
          token: 9a61564f-eff0-4f1c-998b-9a1698e26615
          files: ./coverage/clover.xml

          # coverage settings
          coverage:
            status:
              project:
                default:
                  target: auto
                  # adjust accordingly based on how flaky your tests are
                  # this allows a 10% drop from the previous base commit coverage
                  threshold: 10%
```

Comment: 1. Can you please share the error message you get? (paste directly, not link). 2. I'm pretty sure you cannot pass nested values like you did to the action (perhaps the config file is picked up from the repository if it exists?).

Comment: Tom from Codecov here. The Codecov output would be great. Also, just checking that the `#coverage settings` and beneath are not a part of your workflow, but in the `codecov.yml` Do you have a commit SHA you can share?